# How do I change an instance from a function?

Tags: rust

This is my code

```rust
struct AA{
    size:i8
}
impl AA{
    pub fn create()->Self{
        Self { size: 10 }
    }
    pub fn world(mut self)->Self{
        self.size+=2;
        self
    }
    pub fn say(self){
        println!("{}",self.size);
    }
}

//cannot move out of `*aa` which is behind a mutable reference
fn hello(aa: &mut AA){//this function will make a change
    aa.world();//                  <-- need to call world() from here
}

fn main() {
    let mut a=AA::create();
    hello(&mut a);
    a.say();//                     <-- need to call say() from here after hello() does the change
    //AA::create().world().say();  <-- this works
}
```

How can I achieve the following in rust?

From main(),

1. create instance
2. pass instance to world() so that it can change the instance
3. after the change occurs, call say() of the instance from main

Comment: is there a reason for `world()` to consume the instance? If there is, why can't `hello()` do the same (consume the instance and return a new one)?

Comment: can you please show some code? @JussiKukkonen
```world()``` meant to modify the private variables

Comment: @KoushikSeal it just needs to take self by mutable reference: `pub fn world(&mut self) { self.size += 2; }`

Comment: That works too, thanks @Masklinn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this alternative work for you?

```
struct AA {
    size: i8,
}

impl AA {
    pub fn create() -> Self {
        Self { size: 10 }
    }
    pub fn world(mut self) -> Self {
        self.size += 2;
        self
    }
    pub fn say(self) {
        println!("{}", self.size);
    }
}

fn hello(aa: AA) -> AA {
    aa.world()
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = AA::create();
    a = hello(a);
    a.say();
}
```

Notice that world returns a Self type and hello also returns `AA`. This way instead of passing a mutable reference to `a` in `hello()` we consume it and return a new version of it.

Another alternative would be for both `world` and `say` to accept references to `self` instead of consuming them, in which case the snippet would be:

```
    pub fn world(&self) -> Self {
        AA {
            size: self.size + 2,
        }
    }
    pub fn say(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.size);
    }
```